# Longest common substring across multiple sequences

Tags: algorithm, perl, lcs

I'm trying to find the longest common substring (LCS) across multiple sequences.

There are a number of modules on CPAN that implement the LCS algorithm for 2 sequences, such as <del>[Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Diff/lib/Algorithm/Diff.pm) and</del> [String::LCSS_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~limaone/String-LCSS_XS-1.2/lib/String/LCSS_XS.pm), but I'm having a hard time in extending them to work with more than 2 sequences because the LCS across multiple sequences is not necessarily a LCS between any two of them.

<del>Of note, despite its name, the [Algorith::MLCS](http://search.cpan.org/~vmoiseev/Algorithm-MLCS-1.02/lib/Algorithm/MLCS.pm) doesn't actually return the LCS but all the common elements (also non-consecutive) of a number of arrays. My impression is that it is broken by design, but I might be wrong.</del>

[Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Diff/lib/Algorithm/Diff.pm) and [Algorith::MLCS](http://search.cpan.org/~vmoiseev/Algorithm-MLCS-1.02/lib/Algorithm/MLCS.pm) solve the longest common *subsequence* problem, not the longest common *substring* one.

Is there an obvious way to extend the n=2 algorithms or do I have to implement my version? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I suspect that Algorithm::MLCS is not "broken by design". Rather, it's solving a different problem. It deals with the longest common **subsequence** problem. If I understand your question, you're dealing with the longest common **substring** problem. I think Algorithm::Diff is the same: it deals with the subsequence problem.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I didn't get there was a difference between substring and subsequence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved pretty easily using the [Tree::Suffix](http://search.cpan.org/~gray/Tree-Suffix-0.21/lib/Tree/Suffix.pm) module.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Bio::SeqIO;
use Tree::Suffix;

my $seqio = Bio::SeqIO->new(
    -file => "fasta_sequences.txt",
    -format => "Fasta");

my @seqs;

while (my $seqobj = $seqio->next_seq) {
    push @seqs, $seqobj->seq;
}

my $tree = Tree::Suffix->new(@seqs);
my @lcss = $tree->lcs;

say $_ for @lcss;
```